# Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Tags: apache, configuration, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I have configured my Apache by myself and have tried to load [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) on a virtual host, but I received:

> 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

My httpd.conf

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
# In particular, see
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/foo.log".
#
# NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
# instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
# If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
# will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
# an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
# at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
# httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

Include conf/vhosts.conf

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule php5_module "c:/Program Files/php/php5apache2_2.dll"

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.example
#
ServerAdmin webmaster@somenet.example

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.somenet.example:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.somenet.example/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.somenet.example/subscription_info.html
#

#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or one of the special
# values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
#MaxRanges unlimited

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

PHPIniDir "c:/Program Files/php"
```

and vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot i:/projects/webserver/__tools/phpmyadmin/
    ServerName dbadmin.tools
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What are the rights of http folder and who owns it?

Comment: It's on my local machine under windows 7, and what folder do you mean? i:/projects/webserver/__tools/phpmyadmin/?

Comment: yes apache runs as user daemon. Does this user has the right to read the files?

Comment: yes, I am under administrator

Comment: I have tested something, it looks like PHP don't work, because HTML index works on localhost but PHP is not. But on domain dbadmin.tools PHP and HTML indexes aren't work :(

Comment: check if you don't have an `.htaccess` file that overrides to deny access (in the directory) you are trying to access

Comment: I got this error after renaming my root directory. After rebooting the system it went away.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: one edge case: check that your directory is Not empty and atleast has default index 'index.html' file

Answer (score 707, accepted):

## Update October 2016

4 years ago, since this answer is used as a reference by many, and while I learned a lot from security perspective during these years,
I feel I am responsible to clarify some important notes, and I've update my answer accordingly.

The original answer is correct but not safe for some production environments,
in addition I would like to explain some issues that you might fall into while setting up your environment.

**If you are looking for a quick solution and SECURITY IS NOT A MATTER, i.e development env, skip and read the original answer instead**

Many scenarios can lead to **403 Forbidden**:

---

### A. Directory Indexes (from `mod_autoindex.c`)

When you access a directory and there is no default file found in this directory
**AND** Apache `Options Indexes` is not enabled for this directory.

#### A.1. `DirectoryIndex` option example

`DirectoryIndex index.html default.php welcome.php`

#### A.2. `Options Indexes` option

If set, Apache will list the directory content if no default file found (from the above  option)

#### If none of the conditions above is satisfied

You will receive a **403 Forbidden**

#### Recommendations

- You should not allow directory listing unless **REALLY** needed.
- Restrict the default index `DirectoryIndex` to the minimum.
- If you want to modify, restrict the modification to the needed directory ONLY, for instance, use `.htaccess` files, or put your modification inside the `<Directory /my/directory>` directive

---

### B. `deny,allow` directives (Apache 2.2)

*Mentioned by @Radu, @Simon A. Eugster in the comments*
You request is denied, blacklisted or whitelisted by those directives.

I will not post a full explanation, but I think some examples may help you understand,
in short remember this rule:

**IF MATCHED BY BOTH, THE LAST DIRECTIVE IS THE ONE THAT WILL WIN**

### `Order allow,deny`

Deny will win if matched by both directives (even if an `allow` directive is written after the `deny` in the conf)

### `Order deny,allow`

allow will win if matched by both directives

#### Example 1

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from localhost mydomain.example
```

Only `localhost` and `*.mydomain.example` can access this, all other hosts are denied

#### Example 2

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from evil.example
Allow from safe.evil.example # <-- has no effect since this will be evaluated first
```

All requests are denied, the last line may trick you, but remember that if matched by both the last win rule (here Deny is the last), same as written:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from safe.evil.example
Deny from evil.example # <-- will override the previous one
```

#### Example 4

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from site.example
Deny from untrusted.site.example # <-- has no effect since this will be matched by the above `Allow` directive
```

Requests are accepted from all hosts

#### Example 4: typical for public sites (allow unless blacklisted)

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from hacker1.example
Deny from hacker2.example
```

#### Example 5: typical for intranet and secure sites (deny unless whitelisted)

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from mypc.localdomain
Allow from managment.localdomain
```

---

### C. `Require` directive (Apache 2.4)

Apache 2.4 use a new module called `mod_authz_host`

`Require all granted` => Allow all requests

`Require all denied` => Deny all requests

`Require host safe.example` => Only from `safe.example` are allowed

---

### D. Files permissions

One thing that most people do it wrong is configuring files permissions,

The GOLDEN RULE is

**STARTS WITH NO PERMISSION AND ADD AS PER YOUR NEED**

In Linux:

- Directories should have the `Execute` permission
- Files should have the `Read` permission
- YES, you are right DO NOT ADD `Execute` permission for files

for instance, I use this script to setup the folders permissions

```
# setting permissions for /var/www/mysite.example

# read permission ONLY for the owner
chmod -R /var/www/mysite.example 400

# add execute for folders only
find /var/www/mysite.example -type d -exec chmod -R u+x {} \;

# allow file uploads
chmod -R /var/www/mysite.example/public/uploads u+w

# allow log writing to this folder
chmod -R /var/www/mysite.example/logs/
```

*I posted this code as an example, setup may vary in other situations*

---

---

## Original Answer

I faced the same issue, but I solved it by setting the **options** directive either in the global directory setting in the `httpd.conf` or in the specific directory block in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

By default, your global directory settings is `(httpd.conf line ~188)`:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

set the options to:
`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI`

Finally, it should look like:

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also try changing `Order deny,allow` and `Allow from all` lines  by `Require all granted`.

#### Appendix

### Directory Indexes source code (some code remove for brevity)

```
if (allow_opts & OPT_INDEXES) {
     return index_directory(r, d);
} else {
        const char *index_names = apr_table_get(r->notes, "dir-index-names");

        ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, 0, r, APLOGNO(01276)
                      "Cannot serve directory %s: No matching DirectoryIndex (%s) found, and "
                      "server-generated directory index forbidden by "
                      "Options directive",
                       r->filename,
                       index_names ? index_names : "none");
        return HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
    }
```

Comment: Also, one should check the folder's permissions so that the Apache process' owner has permissions to read/execute the specified path for the virtual host. On Windows this could rarely be a problem but on Linux it can be a more frequent cause of 403.

Comment: httpd.conf on my Ubuntu is empty and httpd-vhosts.conf cannot be found.

Comment: I additionally had to change `Order deny,allow, Allow from all` to `Require all granted` on Apache 2.4. See here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: only after adding `Require all granted` it worked

Comment: @pylover Doesn't and mess up my configuration... (and the one of this guy too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263135/apache-500-internal-server-error-on-my-virtual-host)

Comment: In addition to this following step is required  find the line > Listen 80
and change to > listen 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: @Radu this comment could be an answer since your comment solved the issue for me.

Comment: I also needed to add index.html or index.php to the root directory

Comment: I only had to add _Indexes_ after that everything worked fine. So my _Options_ line ended up looking like this: `Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes`

Comment: In the recent version of apache (2.4.7) httpd.conf has been renamed to apache2.conf

Comment: Not working for me. I solved this issue by run `chmod` in terminal.

Comment: After this changes you must **Restart All Services**.

Comment: All this didn't work for me, finally changing User _www to my username in httpd.conf worked.

Comment: Worked for me. Win8.1 + Apache2.4 + PHP5.6 + mod_fcgid (fast CGI)

Comment: this is not working for me.

Comment: Did not have to change 'Options'. Only changed: 'Require all granted' and in the envvars file in /etc/apache2, changed 'export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data' to 'export APACHE_RUN_USER=[my_username]'

Comment: This answer is **SO WRONG**! You should **NEVER** set `Allow from all` in the `<Directory />` section of `httpd.conf` Thats just a hackers **delight**

Comment: @RiggsFolly If you read well the answer, you will notice, that what I am suggesting is to modify the `Options` param and not the `Allow`

Comment: But you still have `Allow from all` in the `<Directory />` The `<Directory />` section **should** protect the root folder and all subfolders from all access. Then you allow access to only the directories that Apache actually requires access to. Then if you are hacked the hacker does not gain access to all your file system from a hacked Apache. [See Protect Server Files by Default](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html)

Comment: I got a 403 forbidden, and add `Require all granted `, and now it works ...

Comment: can I edit all the conf files to make allow from all in place of deny

Comment: Aren't these chmod arguments backwards? According to [die](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod), the file always goes last

Comment: If the 'Original answer' needs to be used, then the conf file to be updated is changed from /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to /etc/apache2/apache.conf

Comment: SELinux types was my issue. As this is the accepted answer it may be helpful to reference @Dominic/@Peter Mortensen answer below

Comment: For a quick fix, I had to create `.htaccess` in the Laravel root folder and added these lines of code to give acess to the public folder as shown below, and everything worked like magic.            `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: chmod -R /var/www/mysite.example 400
chmod: invalid mode: ‘/var/www/mysite.example’

Answer (score 199):

I understand this issue is resolved but I happened to solve this same problem on my own.

The cause of

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

is actually the default configuration for an apache directory in `httpd.conf`.

```
#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory "/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all          # the cause of permission denied
</Directory>
```

Simply changing `Deny from all` to `Allow from all` should solve the permission problem.

Alternatively, a better approach would be to specify individual directory permissions on virtualhost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ....

    # Set access permission
    <Directory "/path/to/docroot">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

As of **Apache-2.4**, however, access control is done using the new module `mod_authz_host` ([Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)). Consequently, the new `Require` directive should be used.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ....

    # Set access permission
    <Directory "/path/to/docroot">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Apache/2.2.24 on OSX 10.6.8.  1) This post, and 2) the instructions here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/ (You will get a warning that the line `NameVirtualHost *:80` does nothing, so you can delete it.  You also have to create the directory for the logfiles.), and...

Comment: 3) adding the line `127.0.0.1       web_site_name.com` to the bottom of the file /private/etc/hosts worked for me.  If you have Apache setup to listen on, say, port 8080, then use `<VirtualHost *:8080>`, and 
just as you have to use the url `http://localhost:8080`, you will need to use the url `http://web_site_name.com:8080`.  4) In the end, I went with @hmoyat's <Directory> configuration(in one of the other answers) because it seems more specific.

Comment: after adding 'Require all granted' now instead of default apache page I see this: 'Mcrypt PHP extension required.' (it's already installed). What do I do now?

Comment: Hi @eagor. Be sure to also enable the MCrypt extension (not just install it). That error is also more related to PHP than Apache so you'll want to try http://stackoverflow.com/q/16830405/1349295 or similar threads.

Comment: Require all granted solve my problem

Comment: I used require all granted doesnot solve my problem. Some this error occurred. I used to change the owner using  ` sudo chown www-data:www-data file`

Comment: Please be patient with granting access to your root directory. It is unsecure. Better is to grant access to particular directory (you want to show to public).

Comment: @shehbazali, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/14623574/1349295 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14075646/1349295. They have, on some occasions, solved this issue for me as well.

Comment: I tried both solution. I don't know why this is not working?  @CzarPino can you tell me why this error happen 403? Is this only for user permission and file mode.

Comment: I do not find 'httpd.conf' file in my root!! Using apache2 web server.

Comment: Do you understand what `<Directory /> Allow from all </Directory>` is actually doing. I guess not! That gives Apache full access to your whole filesystem. **Very dangerous if your site gets hacked!!**

Comment: To those that used `<Directory />`, the recommended way of setting up access permission is per directory (i.e. `<Directory "/path/to/docroot">`). My previous example used `<Directory />` which apparently grants remote host access to the entire filesystem. I am currently unaware exactly how this can be leveraged by a cracker except that providing more permissions than needed is a basic security no-no. I've updated my answer for posterity's sake. Apologies for the lacking insight on security.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html#protectserverfiles

Answer (score 138):

A common gotcha for directories hosted outside of the default /var/www/ is that the Apache user doesn't just need permissions to the directory and subdirectories where the site is being hosted.  Apache requires permissions to all the directories all the way up to the root of the file system where the site is hosted.  Apache automatically gets permissions assigned to /var/www/ when it's installed, so if your host directory is directly underneath that then this doesn't apply to you.  Edit: Daybreaker has reported that his Apache was installed without correct access permissions to the default directory.

For example, you've got a development machine and your site's directory is:

```
/username/home/Dropbox/myamazingsite/
```

You may think you can get away with:

```
chgrp -R www-data /username/home/Dropbox/myamazingsite/
chmod -R 2750 /username/home/Dropbox/myamazingsite/
```

because this gives Apache permissions to access your site's directory?  Well that's correct but it's not sufficient.  Apache requires permissions all the way up the directory tree so what you need to do is:

```
chgrp -R www-data /username/
chmod -R 2750 /username/
```

Obviously I would not recommend giving access to Apache on a production server to a complete directory structure without analysing what's in that directory structure.  For production it's best to keep to the default directory or another directory structure that's just for holding web assets.

Edit2: as u/chimeraha pointed out, if you're not sure what you're doing with the permissions, it'd be best to move your site's directory out of your home directory to avoid potentially locking yourself out of your home directory.

Comment: Your answer helped out a lot. For some reason my /var/www wasnt set up  for access by the apache user. Thanks!

Comment: I just did this and went from "Apache doesn't have permission" to "500 Internal Server Error" :(

Comment: @Craig That's progress.  It means you've solved your initial permissions problem.  Start looking through your Apache / application log files to determine what's causing the 500 error.

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I successfully locked out myself from the /home directory tree... :)

Comment: Doing this: chgrp -R apache /username/ fixed the problem for me!  but just like Edifice, now I can't access my home directory tree unless I chgrp back to my user.  So now I need to change to my original user to pull in my changes via git.  Then change back to apache to redeploy my server.  Is this the only way?

Comment: @anc1revv Is this a development machine or a production machine?

Comment: @GilesRoberts this would be on my production machine.  What ended up working for me is just changing the user and group in my httpd to be my username.  Is there any downfall to doing that?

Comment: @anc1revv Unsure.  You'd have to find someone better versed in Linux security than me to answer that.  Perhaps worth Googling or asking as a separate question.  For me I generally don't use Git for deployment as I don't want my whole development environment replicated to the deployed site.  I generally use a script or deployment tool.  Just out of interest, if this is a production server, why are you outside of the normal Apache web serving directory?

Comment: @GilesRoberts I developed my django app locally, then I just pushed my project to my ec2 instance using git.  And from there I wanted to deploy my app. The way django is set up, the project is typically not copied to the web serving directory. I followed this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: chmod -R  2750    - what could mean number 2 ?  7 - rwe permissions for owner, 5 - re for group, and 0 - nothing for others. But what is  2 ? Thanks

Comment: @gekannt  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_modes  The chmod numeric format accepts up to four octal digits. The rightmost three refer to permissions for the file owner, the group, and other users. The next digit (fourth from the right) specifies special setuid, setgid, and sticky flags.

Comment: @gekannt But use whatever permissions you'd normally use for securing a web directory.  The above permissions are only an example that fit with my personal dev environment.

Comment: @gekannt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Special_modes  Some more detail on 4 digit file system permissions.

Comment: Thank you. The user directory used to host was in 700 and it didn't occur to me to check it out before reading your answer.

Comment: the upper level folder works for me when it is 755, while 750 is not working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Before locking your home directory (LOL), I would highly recommend adding "Require all granted"

Comment: My other website in the localhost is working. But, this project is not working. and giving 403 Error.

Comment: Thanks it is very useful!

Comment: Does anyone know how to give the home directory back to the user?

Comment: This answer resolved the problem for me when everything else was setup correctly. I was pulling my hair out and then came to find out that the /var/www directory somehow inexplicably had different permissions other than Apache. 

find /var/www -exec chown apache:apache {} \;

And Boom! 

Problem solved....

Comment: One reason this is a hair puller is that many people simply try to copy the default vhost and substitute values for their own site and try to simply replicate the permissions on the /var/www path to their own path (e.g. /srv/data/mysite). But then even though the permissions may be identical (and correct) they still get the "Forbidden" message. This seems like a mystery until you realize that what makes `/var/www` particular to Apache is nothing more than the fact that it is also explicitly configured inside httpd.conf (apache2.conf in Ubuntu) to further enable a number of other directives.

Answer (score 70):

Some configuration parameters have changed in Apache 2.4. I had a similar issue when I was setting up a [Zend Framework 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework#Requirements) application. After some research, here is the solution:

***Incorrect Configuration***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny #<-- 2.2 config
        Allow from all #<-- 2.2 config
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

***Correct Configuration***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted #<-- 2.4 New configuration
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are planning to migrate from Apache 2.2 to 2.4, here is a good reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Thanks! You answer is right on the mark!

Answer (score 48):

With **Apache 2.2**

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

With **Apache 2.4**

```
Require all granted
```

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html

Comment: This is an important difference. `Allow from all` will not work in Apache 2.4.

Comment: Thank you @mpgn, you have helped me a lot.

Comment: This is the answer which i was searching for

Answer (score 25):

On **Ubuntu 14.04** using **Apache 2.4**, I did the following:

Add the following in the file, **apache2.conf** (under `/etc/apache2`):

```
<Directory /home/rocky/code/documentroot/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and reload the server:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Edit: This also works on OS X Yosemite with Apache 2.4. The all-important line is

> Require all granted

Answer (score 25):

If you are using CentOS with [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) Try:

```
sudo restorecon -r /var/www/html
```

See more: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6834#p31548

Answer (score 23):

If you are using a [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server then try this:

- Single click on the WAMP server icon at the taskbar
- Select the option **put online**
- Your server will restart automatically
- Then try to access your localwebsite

Answer (score 20):

I solved my problem by adding my user to `httpd.conf`.

```
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
#User daemon
User my_username
Group daemon
```

Comment: The answer doesn't make sense. `User` is given twice and the last `User` is `myuser`, whats-up with `User deamon`? Also please fix the style of your answer, it is quite unreadable what should be in the `httpd.conf` and what not. It also fails to explain why this solves the problem

Comment: I just changed my "user" and "group" to my user name and this worked for me as well.

Comment: You sir are a godsend! I couldn't figure this out and updating both my user and group to the user I was under worked great. Happened when I copied a production VM and was setting up a new user for development VM.

Comment: This answer was the most helpful for me

Answer (score 14):

This article [Creating virtual hosts on Apache 2.2](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache22_vhosts.php) helps me (point 9) permissions to the top virtual hosts directory.

I simply add this lines to my vhosts.conf file:

```
<Directory I:/projects/webserver>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I am facing problem, i changed the document root path in my ubuntu 14.04 from /var/www/html/ to /media/user/projects/php/ :  DocumentRoot /media/mithun/Projects/Sites/php
 
 <Directory /media/user/projects/php/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None 
   Require all granted
 </Directory> Its not working. Anyhelp?

Answer (score 12):

I was getting the same error and couldn't figure out the problem for ages. If you happen to be on a Linux distribution that includes [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) such as [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), you need to make sure SELinux permissions are set correctly for your document root files or you will get this error. This is a completely different set of permissions to the standard file system permissions.

I happened to use the tutorial *[Apache and SELinux](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/web-server/976-apache-and-selinux)*, but there seems to be plenty around once you know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks! SELinux was causing my problems. I disabled it and now I can access my html files which were outside of the default /var/www/ directory. Now I'll take a look at this tutorial to see if I can get it enabled and configured so I can still access my files.

Comment: Do you know why the `restorecon /var/www/*` command would bring everything back to `var_t` instead of `http_sys_content_t` or `tmp_t`? Type `var_t` causes a `403 Forbidden` error.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using MAMP Pro the way to fix this is by checking the `Indexes` checkbox under the `Hosts` - `Extended` tab.

In MAMP Pro v3.0.3 this is what that looks like:
[image]

Comment: thanks it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to solve this problem. Let us say you want to access directory "subphp" which exist at `/var/www/html/subphp`, and you want to access it using `127.0.0.1/subphp` and you receive error like this:

> You don't have permission to access /subphp/ on this server.

Then change the directory permissions from "None" to "access files". A command-line user can use the [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command to change the permission.

Comment: Is there any half upvote option?

Answer (score 4):

(In Windows and Apache 2.2.x)

The "Forbidden" error is also the result of not having virtual hosts defined.

As noted by Julien, if you intend to use virtual `hosts.conf`, then go to the httpd file and uncomment the following line:

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then add your virtual hosts definitions in `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and restart Apache.

Answer (score 4):

I use Mac OS X, in my case, I just forget to enable php in apache, all I need to do is to uncomment one line from `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

ref [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/10/enable-php-apache-mac-os-x/) article for detail.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but due to the fact that I changed the path on apache to a folder outside var/www, I started running into problems.

I fixed it by creating a symlink in var/www/html > home/dev/project which seemed to do the trick, without having to change any permissions...

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me too much work knowing this!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem, and my solution was moreso that www-data didn't own the proper folders, and instead I set it for one of the users to own it. (I was trying to do a bit of fancy, but erroneous trickery to get ftp to play nicely.)

After running:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

The machine started serving data again. You can see who currently owns the folder by means of

```
ls -l /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and don't add anything `Order allow,deny` and others:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py 
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

### *This solution doesn't Allow from all*

I just want to change my public directory www, and access it from my PC, and mobile connected by Wifi. I've Ubuntu 16.04.

1. So, first, I modified **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** 
   and I changed the line DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   for my new public directory
   DocumentRoot "/media/data/XAMPP/htdocs"
2. Then I modified /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, and I put the permissions for localhost, and my mobile, this time I used the IP address, I know it is not completely safe, but it's OK for my purposes.

   ```
   <Directory/>
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from localhost 10.42.0.11
   </Directory>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

RiggsFolly answered this for me elsewhere, simply:

in your apache conf folder edit file: **httpd-vhost.conf**:

Add this little line inside the Directory nest:

```
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Restart the server, apache or Wamp or whatever you have.

That's it, now all your HOME deivces (in ip range 192.168.1.xxx) can see your PC server. Note you only add the first 3 parts of ip number).

Any problems, exit your firewall to test.

To see your network devices ip numbers, download an "IP Scanner" software (quite a few free ones around) for PC or for android get Fing from play store.

Answer (score 1):

```
    I changed 
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All      in .htaccess to   " Require all denied "    and restarted apache but it did not help.
```

Path for apache2.conf in ubuntu is /etc/apache2/apache.conf

Then I added following lines in apache2.conf and then my folder is working fine

```
    <Directory /path of required folder>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
       </Directory>

   and run  " Sudo service apache2 restart "
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has several answers already, but I think there is a very subtle aspect that, although mentioned, hasn't been highlighted enough in the previous answers.

Before checking the Apache configuration or your files' permissions, let's do a simpler check to make sure that **each** of the directories composing the full path to the file you want to access (e.g. the index.php file in your document's root) is not only readable but also **executable** by the web server user.

For example, let's say the path to your documents root is "/var/www/html". You have to make sure that all of the "var", "www" and "html" directories are (readable and) executable by the web server user. In my case (Ubuntu 16.04) I had mistakenly removed the "x" flag to the "others" group from the "html" directory so the permissions looked like this:

```
drwxr-xr-- 15 root root 4096 Jun 11 16:40 html
```

As you can see the web server user (to whom the "others" permissions apply in this case) didn't have *execute* access to the "html" directory, and this was exactly the root of the problem. After issuing a:

```
chmod o+x html
```

command, the problem got fixed!

Before resolving this way I had literally tried every other suggestion in this thread, and since the suggestion was buried in a comment that I found almost by chance, I think it may be helpful to highlight and expand on it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a specific controller only - which was really weird. I had a folder in the root of the CI folder that had the same name as the controller I was trying to access... Because of that, CI was directing the request to this directory instead of the controller itself.

After removing this folder (which was there a bit by mistake), it all worked fine.

To be more clear, here is what it looked like:

```
/ci/controller/register.php

/ci/register/
```

I had to remove `/ci/register/`.

Comment: sometimes codeigniter uses .htaccess files to stop direct access.  have a look with ls -Al to ensure there are no hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Check exactly where you are putting your files, don't nest them in the Documents folder.

For instance I made the mistake of putting my code in the Documents folder of as mentioned this isn't going to work because Documents is explicitly only available to YOU and not APACHE.  Try moving it up one directory and you may not see this issue.

Move folder from:

/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Documents/code

To here:
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/code

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring another contribution as I ran to this problem too:

I had a VirtualHost configured that I did not want to. I have commented out the line where the include for the vhost occured, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the configuration files don't forget to `Restart All Services`.

I wasted three hours of my time on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `youralias.conf` file like this code:

```
Alias /Quiz/ "h:/MyServer/Quiz/" 
 <Directory "h:/MyServer/Quiz/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   <IfDefine APACHE24>
     Require local
   </IfDefine>
   <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
   </IfDefine>
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the correct file to be configured in this situation is not the httpd.conf in the phpMyAdmin alias, but in `bin/apache/your_version/conf/httpd.conf`.

Look for the following line:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Make sure it is set to `Allow from all`...

If not, phpMyAdmin might even work, but not your root and other folders under it. Also, remember to restart WAMP and then put online...

This solved my headache.

Comment: This answer is **SO WRONG**! You should **NEVER** set `Allow from all` or `Require all granted` in the `<Directory />` section of `httpd.conf` Thats just a hackers **delight**

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to mount the files in my VirtualBox guest from my local filesystem before running a docker build. In the end, the "fix" was to copy all the files to the VirtualBox instance rather than building from inside the SSHFS mount, and then run the build from there.

Answer (score 0):

***WORKING Method (unless there is no other problem)***

**By default, Apache is not restricting access from [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) (common external IP address)**

What are restricted are the commands given in '`httpd.conf`'.

Replace all

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    # Require all denied
</Directory>
```

hence removing out all restriction given to *Apache*.

Replace `Require local` with `Require all granted` for the *C:/wamp/www/* directory.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    # Require local
</Directory>
```

Comment: Is it really "<Directory />" (two instances)? Shouldn't it be "<Directory>"?

Comment: The first receives the dir path <Directory {/path/to/your/dir}>

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ridiculous, but I got the 403 Forbidden when the file I was trying to download wasn't there on the filesystem. The apache error is not very accurate in this case, and the whole thing worked after I simply put the file where it was supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

We had modsec enabled, check the site's error log for an modsec ID then enter a locationmatch for the file in the vhost (or .htaccess I guess):

```
 <LocationMatch "/yourlocation/index.php">
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleRemoveById XXXXXXX
    </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another potential gotcha to this growing list, my problem (running CentOS 6.8) was with a particular virtualhost which worked fine on a different server, the issue turned out to be a faulty .htaccess file using mod_rewrite:

In .htaccess, this caused a 403 error:

    `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>`

Adding **FollowSymLinks** as the first line fixed the issue:

    `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

**Permissions error**

Some very noob users like me face this problem when having incorrect permissions set in a page (in particular, that "other" users do not have **read permissions**). For example, say you are attempting to access index.html, and you get the above error. To fix, type:

```
chmod o+r index.html
```

and then upload to server again. Error disappears.