# Apache 500 Internal Server Error on my virtual host

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, lamp, vhosts

I have my web app projects located in a folder in /media/disk1/Projects. I want to serve them using an Apache virtualhost at `http://lab/`.

This is how I set up my virtual host:

**1. Copied /etc/apache2/sites-available/default to /etc/apache2/sites-available/lab**

**2. Edited /etc/apache2/sites-available/lab to the following:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin tim@localhost
ServerName lab

DocumentRoot /media/disk1/Projects
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
# <Directory /var/www/>
<Directory /media/disk1/Projects>
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

**3. Added `127.0.0.1 lab` to my /etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   lab
```

**4. Accessed `http://lab` only to get `500 Internal Server Error`**

All the subfolder permissions are set to drwxrwxrwx 
But my `http://lab/phpmyadmin` works.

Help me resolve. Thanks.

Comment: What does your error logs say?

Comment: Soo much. Here I just uploaded my /var/log/apache2/error.log http://goo.gl/DSjhEf

Comment: And here is my /var/log/apache2/access.log http://goo.gl/IuXT9a

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Error solved by checking this forum; http://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=8603
On my /var/log/apache2/error.log the last error was:

```
[Wed Oct 09 09:10:04 2013] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /
```

So I followed someone elses solution and commented the line

```
# Require all granted
```

just under  on my /etc/apache2/sites-available/lab and TADA! I was able to list my Projects directory in my browser.

Comment: That's the correct answer that fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed mine too although I can't explain why!!

Comment: Commenting that line made my error transform into 403 forbidden, so clearly it is not always redundant.