# Blank page and error 500 on ubuntu virtual desktop 18.04 respect to ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, http-status-code-500

Hy, 
I've an Ubuntu server 18.04 where the following addresses of my web application are correctly working:

http://server:port/user-dashboards/solergy/
http://server:port/

instead on an ubuntu 18.04 with virtual desktop enabled only the first is available
http://server:port/user-dashboards/solergy/

instead looking for the second
http://server:port/
the result is a blank page and error 500,

but I can't see any problem in the web application log.

How I can discover where is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: It's up to you if we can see the log file or not it may be helpful... But perhaps its a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263135/apache-500-internal-server-error-on-my-virtual-host

Comment: there are no info on /var/log/syslog and apache is not used. And also application logs are empty when I require page  http://server:port/ .Which Ubuntu log file can I check

Comment: What service are you using? So I can better grasp the answer

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, my application software needs Oracle jdk1.8 instead on the server there was openjdk, there must be some difference, thanks for your help