# Getting 403 Forbidden Error Using web2py with Apache2 WSGI on Fedora

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, web2py

I'm getting 403 Forbidden with the webpage displaying:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

The access log shows the following corresponding to this:

```
[Mon Jan 20 17:12:03.888576 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1940] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:32491] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/web-apps/web2py/wsgihandler.py
```

I've the following permissions set for the above directory:

```
       /]# ls -ld opt
drwxrwxrwx. 4 root root 4096 Jan 10 20:05 opt

     opt]# ls -ld web-apps
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jan 10 20:10 web-apps

web-apps]# ls -ld web2py
drwxr-xr-x 11 apache apache 4096 Jan 10 21:21 web2py

  web2py]# ls -l wsgihandler.py
drwxrwxr-x 1 apache apache 1128 Nov 28 19:23 wsgihandler.py
```

And my conf file /etc/httpd/conf.d/default.conf is as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=apache group=apache processes=1 threads=1
  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/web-apps/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  <Directory /opt/web-apps/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(?:_[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+/)?(.*) /opt/web-apps/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

  <Directory /opt/web-apps/web2py/applications/*/static>
    Options -Indexes
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Location /admin>
    Deny from all
  </Location>

  <LocationMatch ^/([^/]+)/appadmin>
    Deny from all
  </LocationMatch>

  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/self_signed.cert
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/self_signed.key

  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias /web2py /opt/web-apps/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  <Directory /opt/web-apps/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
       Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(?:_[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+/)?(.*) /opt/web-apps/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

  <Directory /opt/web-apps/web2py/applications/*/static>
    Options -Indexes
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is issue if Apache read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: @Yogesh Tried that. and still getting the same error. Added the following:  
    <Directory />
        #Options FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :
first of all if you have linux user apache and group apache then put your web2py directory with /home/apache/ and then change your apache sites-available file like this. hope this will for for you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=apache group=apache display-name=%{GROUP}
  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/apache/web2py/wsgihandler.py

  <Directory /home/apache/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(.*) /users/apache/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2
  <Directory /users/apache/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you using virtualenv check your wsgi file as well like this :

```
activate_this = '/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this)
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/web2py_dir')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly because your apache2 version is 2.4.
You will need to upgrade you conf file..
Follow the link [Upgrading apache2 to 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)