# Apache Gives me 403 Error when trying to access "/" on server

Tags: php, html, apache

When I try to change the web root path to any other folder it give me a 403 error (Forbidden), The default path is `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, but since this rather annoying for me, I changed it too `/Users/Xero/WebServer`

## Permissions

I got the permissions from `/Library/WebServer/Documents` by right clicking and selecting `Get info` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeX2b.png What it looks like)

So I changed it to be the exact same for `/Users/Xero/WebServer`. But it give me a 403 error still.

---

## Attempt to fix

So, I looked it up on Google, and I tried these solutions to fix my problem:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/

[Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) (Stack Overflow)

But they didn't help.

---

## Other Notes

Remember I'm using the preinstalled Apache on OS X Snow leopard. And, my virtual host isn't local, so it's not part or the `hosts` file issue (It's hosted off my DNS, and my IP as a backup, neither work)

My Virtual Hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                      ( Edited 2 )
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Xero/WebServer" 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        DocumentRoot "/Users/Xero/WebServer"
        ServerName wrks.tk
        ErrorLog "/Logs/Workarea/wrks-err"
        CustomLog "/Logs/Workarea/wrks-acc" common
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml
        <Directory "/Users/Xero/WebServer">
                Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/Xero/WebServer"
        ServerName 209.169.203.53
        ErrorLog "/Logs/Workarea/ip"
        CustomLog "/Logs/Workarea/ip-acc" common
        <Directory "/Users/Xero/WebServer">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I have my httpd.conf `User` and `Group` setup like this:

```
User _www
Group _www
```

---

## Responses to Answers

---

## Edits

1. So, I fixed the path's to the document's, but it still giving me the same error, 403.
2. I checked my FireWall settings and it's off. I also checked my `Sharing Preferences`, `File Sharing` and `Web Sharing` are on.
3. I edited the duplicate of `DirectoryIndex Home.php Home.html` in the `wrks.tk` VirtualHost, but still, I'm getting the same error. (See Other Notes)
4. **Added more too Other Notes.**
5. Fixed directory, but still didn't fix problem.
6. Added another to Answer Responses.
7. Tried a computer restart, did not work.
8. I put a `index.html` in the folder, still got the same 403 error, I tried accessing `/index.html`, still, 403.

Comment: sudo chown -R www-data /Users/Xero/WebServer ..... chmod -R 644 /Users/Xero/WebServer

Comment: Please avoid answering in the comments (So I can vote for a answer if I get one). But I'll give it a try.

Comment: @RobertRozas The first one gave this error:
`chown: www-data: Invalid argument`
And the second one did not fix the problem.

Comment: Check the user of the /var/www folder...you have to give that user ownership over /Users/Xero/WebServer and the right perms...in osx the user is not www-data(my mistake) but _www

Comment: @RobertRozas Okay, check the 4th edit, and I'll try it again.

Comment: @RobertRozas Still doesn't work.

Comment: sudo chgrp _www /path/to/upload/folder
sudo chmod 664 /path/to/upload/folder

Comment: you have to fix the permissions for the parent directories too.

Answer (score 0):

What file exactly are you getting all of this from?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                      ( Edited 2 )
DocumentRoot "/Users/Xero/WebServer" 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Xero/WebServer"
    ServerName wrks.tk
    ErrorLog "/Logs/Workarea/wrks-err"
    CustomLog "/Logs/Workarea/wrks-acc" common
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml
    <Directory "/Users/Xero/WebServer">
            Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Xero/WebServer"
    ServerName 209.169.203.53
    ErrorLog "/Logs/Workarea/ip"
    CustomLog "/Logs/Workarea/ip-acc" common
    <Directory "/Users/Xero/WebServer">
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There are more than one file for those settings. If you have apache, then take a look in the `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` folders.

---

Change the bottom part of your `httpd.conf` file to:

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

---

Make a new file `index.html` and put the following in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>It works!</h1>

<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Then place the `index.html` file into the empty directory.

---

create a file in `/etc/apache2/users/` called `yourusername.conf` (yourusername being the account short name, e.g. hulu – it's usually the name of your home folder in /Users) with the following contents:

```
<Directory "/Users/yourusername/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: From `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: Are you using lampp? or apache?

Comment: Apache, I'm using the preinstalled OS X (Snow Leopard) version.

Comment: Yes, I do.  But it's not "Exactly" the same, but it's very similar

Comment: Added a bit of a change, after you change it, restart apache.

Comment: Do you have any kind of document that you could test?

Comment: Nope, the folder is just empty, it is supposed to give me a list of the things in the folder, and if there is nothing, it should give me a list of nothing.

Comment: Try the most recent suggestion at the bottom of my answer, it it works then then its a setting to change the way you view directories.

Comment: added another suggestion.