# Can't access images in docker php image

Tags: php, image, apache, docker, localhost

I got a small PHP website with some js and wanted to run it with docker. Because it's a gallery, it has images in a subfolder. The main index.php runs fine, except no images are found. I looked inside the folder with the normal docker CLI and an '*echo ls ...*', but everything is in there. If I go to localhost:8080/images, I get the Error 403 (consol print bellow).

The Images are loaded via php, which generates paths like: '*/var/www/html/images/2555-P160-05.jpg*'. Are they maybe wrong?

---

**Solution**: I got the wrong paths. I'm now getting the pathname via

```
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 
                "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

instead of *getcwd()*. The comments reminded me to check the images directly and not the entire folder. I also edited the Dockerfile and removed the permission changes.

---

OS: Ubuntu 19.04
Docker -v: 19.03.6

Here are my latest edits:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version:  '3'
services:
  photography-website:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.4-apache
```

Error 403:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2020:23:19:48 +0000] "GET /images/ HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What OS are you using? And it is Docker tools or Native Docker? In windows, Docker Tools works only inside your user directory (%userprofile%) ... in Native Docker for WIndows 10... you need to mount the drive you are using... could be that the problem? Try to work inside your %userprofile% dir, for example, inside Documents

Comment: 1) Your `chown` syntax is incorrect. 2) 403 when viewing a *directory* (`GET /images/`) is possibly a separate problem to viewing the images individually, eg maybe due to `DirectorIndex` configuration [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447454/apache-giving-403-forbidden-errors) the many [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959189/apache-virtualhost-403-forbidden) here for [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394871/apache-gives-me-403-error-when-trying-to-access-on-server) suggestions.

Comment: 3) The web server can read your `index.php` without changing its permissions, so changing perms on images is likely not necessary?  You didn't actually describe what happens when you try to view an individual image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths should be *localhost:8080/images/[image].jpg* not *var/www/html/images/[image].jpg*.

More info in my post above.