# Wampserver blocked by Sophos

Tags: server, localhost, block, wampserver, antivirus

I just installed wampserver and when I access it on localhost/ or in 127.0.0.1, The sophos warning "Warning: Questionable Internet use policy" keeps looping back even when i clicked Proceed.

I tried changing the ports to 8383 but to no avail. I remember having the same problem when I was trying to run ASP on IIS but I'm using a different computer now and I can't seem to find it anymore.

BTW, the IT guys are the only ones who have access to sophos but they can't seem to figure out what the problem is as well.

Please tell me if I need to provide anything.

Thanks!

Comment: This is problem of port conflict. WAMP stands for Windows Apache MySQL Php. So you need to set available ports for apache and mysql. Here is more detail about this issue http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2013/04/19/how-to-change-the-port-numbers-on-wamp-and-stop-conflicts-with-a-portable-server/

Comment: It's weird. I tried on Google Chrome and it works when I use localhost:8383 but it doesn't when I use 127.0.0.1:8383. Anyway thanks for this!

Comment: Here is similar post that can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536034/127-0-0-1-not-working-on-wamp-server

Comment: That sounds like its working on IPV6 addresses but not IPV4, have you created a `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file? Possibly you have not set sophos to allow TCP over IPV4 as well