# mod_rewrite no longer taking effect after applying sspi rules in server config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, sspi

I am creating a project in codeIgniter, using wamp to develop on locally (Apache 2.4). Throughout the project I've had mod_rewrite switched on to remove the `index.php` that appears in urls in codeigniter by default by using the `.htaccess` file in the codeigniter project directory i.e. `C:\wamp\www\codeIgniter\.htaccess`.

We needed windows authentication in the application so after finally managing to get the ldap and [sspi](https://www.apachehaus.net/modules/mod_authnz_sspi/) modules working, I applied the following to the  httpd.conf file in `c:wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/codeIgniter">
 AllowOverride None
 Options None
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all

 AuthName "protected"
 AuthType SSPI
 SSPIAuth On
 SSPIAuthoritative On
 SSPIOmitDomain On 

 require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I got this config [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4548).

After making these change to the `httpd.conf` file, the mod_rewrite rules seem to no longer apply and I must write `index.php` after the root of the project to get a url to load.

After reading some of the Apache documentation on setting up `httpd.conf` config and `.htaccess` files it recommends that .htaccess files should not be used if access to the server config is possible:

> In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have
>   access to the main server configuration file. There is, for example, a
>   common misconception that user authentication should always be done in
>   .htaccess files, and, in more recent years, another misconception that
>   mod_rewrite directives must go in .htaccess files. This is simply not
>   the case. You can put user authentication configurations in the main
>   server configuration, and this is, in fact, the preferred way to do
>   things. Likewise, mod_rewrite directives work better, in many
>   respects, in the main server configuration.
>   [Link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

So firstly I'm trying to understand **how I can get my mod_rewrite rules working again happily alongside my sspi stuff** and secondly **how I can move my mod_rewrite rules from .htaccess to my server config file httpd.conf**.

I have tried switching `AllowOverride All` in the server config as in the above-mentioned code but this seems to make everything inaccessible. I have also tried changing `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all` to `Require all granted` but this seems to cause similar issues too. Adding my mod_rewrite rules to the  in the server config also caused everything to be inaccessible. Any guidance would be most appreciated! Thank you.

My `.htaccess` is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeIgniter
#RewriteBase /codeIgniter

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to acces a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on how [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) works.  `None` disables `.htaccess` files.  You need `FileInfo` at a minimum.

Htaccess file processing does incur a performance hit because the access files are read and parsed each request whereas the server and virtual host rules are read and cached at Apache start up.  However, this has to be traded against the flexibility of being able to change your rule processing on a per request rule basis.  For local development, you can ignore this advice.

Also read up on the difference between the per-directory processing of rewrite rules.  In particular, drop the leading `/` characters on any RewriteRule match patterns.  In contrast the Request URI always includes the leading `/`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

makes sense though I am not sure that this is what you are trying to do.

## Postscript

A more elegant way of doing your two rules is to combine them, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(system|application)/
RewriteRule ^.* index.php?/$0 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and the link. If I change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All` or comment it out, which I assume takes any previous directives, such as in `<Directory "c:/wamp/www">` there is `Allow from all` I get the following 403 error: **Forbidden You don't have permission to access /codeIgniter/ on this server.** I can't quite understand why I'm getting this error page, because surely setting `AllowOverride All` or `FileInfo` I am allowing the .htaccess to do it's rewrite work which I assume wouldn't lead to a forbidden error.

Comment: I meant to say in the previous comment "or comment it out, which I assume takes any previous directives, such as in `<Directory "c:/wamp/www">` there is `AllowOverride All`" - won't let me edit

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice given in the answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server#answers-header) and it seemed to solve the issue. So I assume the issue was down altering the options directives.

The parts of my `httpd.conf` file that I changed now look like this:

```
<Directory />
 #AllowOverride none
 #Require all granted

 #Options FollowSymLinks
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride All
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/codeIgniter">
 #AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
 #Options None
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all

 AuthName "protected"
 AuthType SSPI
 SSPIAuth On
 SSPIAuthoritative On
 SSPIOmitDomain On 

 require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I made the changes the rewrite rules @TerryE recommended too in my `.htaccess` file. They now look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/application/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Read up the docs on AllowOverride and Options as I said. Do you really want to allow users to do a directory listing of your codeIgniter folders? I don't know why you'd need anything other than `AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig` and `Options FollowSymLinks`