# permission denied on apache2 with an update to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: symfony, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

i have updated my OS from 12.04 to ubuntu 14.04 and when i try to reload my Symfony2 project i get this error :

```
You don't have permission to access /app_dev.php/ on this server.
```

here's my apache2 file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  s**a
    ServerAlias  d**n

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    DocumentRoot /home/****/


    <Directory />
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <DirectoryMatch .*\.svn/.*>
            Deny From All
        </DirectoryMatch>

    # Logfiles

</VirtualHost>

PS : it works well before the update !
```

Comment: possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: The easiest way I found to sort this was to move my site to `/var/www/my-site-name` (and change the virtual host accordingly). Possibly not the best way to deal with permissions.. I'll give you that.

Comment: @Charles-AntoineFournel i don't have the file httpd.conf ! should i update my apache ?

Comment: try the following command : "find / -name "httpd.conf"

Answer (score 7):

This problem is related to upgrade from `Apache` 2.2 to 2.4 - see [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)

I had similar problem and I changed my `VirtualHost` configuration to something like:

```
<VirtualHost>
    <Directory /home/developer/Projects/sf2/web/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: same problem ! should i change my  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf !
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: I guess so - `Order deny allow` and `Allow from all` directives are no longer valid for `Apache 2.4`