# sub page images failing to load

Tags: javascript, html, image, fullpage.js

I'm trying to load images to this site:

http://btwnthelin.es/wobology/

I've specified them with absolute path, relative path, and even partial path but still they're failing to load.

What is the cause of this? I've not found very much documentation about this issue.

I'm using the template [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), could that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to bring up http://btwnthelin.es/wobology/wobology.jpg directly, I get an error about permissions.

```
**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /wobology/wobology.jpg on this server.


Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at btwnthelin.es Port 80
```

First, verify the path I posted is correct because that is where your page is looking.  Then check the permissions.

And if the path is correct, the images are in the same path as the html, then you don't need to specify a path at all, just the image file name.

Comment: yeah thats totally right. so i just need to `chmod +x wobology.jpg` or something?

Comment: yeah that's true about the path. so it's just that I should change the permissions? maybe with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Give the images the same permissions as the page.

Comment: do i need to do that in the `html.conf` file or something like that or can i just use `chmod`?

Comment: I think chmod should do it.