# Can't access .htaccess; Too many open files

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, xdebug

Recently installed phpStorm and xDebug.
Randomly, I get the following error causing my dev pages to not load:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /admin/subscription/add/16603 on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log` shows:

```
24)Too many open files: [client 127.0.0.1:54206] AH00529:         /Users/jeshuadunham/Sites/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/jeshuadunham/Sites/' is executable, referer: http://dev2.evesun.com/blog/
```

After about 30 seconds, a refresh works normal.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: What are your permissions on your .htaccess file and also on your document root folder?

Comment: @Java-DK I'm using the sugessted Options from that link already.

Comment: @PanamaJack permissions all belong to me except for the log file which needs to be owned by www.

Comment: I mentioned `permissions` not ownership.

Comment: @PanamaJack root folder: drwxr-xr-x 
.htaccess permissions: -rw-r--r--@

Comment: Ok that appears to be normal.  have you experienced this in any other browsers

Comment: No, I'm using chrome but I'll use firefox for a bit to see if it happens there. @PanamaJack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in xdebug.

http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1070

The solution is as follows:

> The workaround I use is to turn off autostart:
>
> xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
>
> Then in Firefox install the Add-on called The Easiest XDebug
>
> In PHPStorm turn on the listener when you want to debug. It won't
>   break unless you click the bug icon in the Firefox toolbar. You might
>   get some errors if you leave the listener on in PHPStorm so turn it
>   off when you're not using it.