# directly access a particular folder/file from application\view folder of codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I need to directly access and browse an particular file from application/views folder. For this I have gave the 755 permission of that file folder.

```
Permission details on folders and files are

    application   755
    views         755
    XX            755
    YY            755
    ZZ.php        755
```

my htaccess code is follows as

```
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Even after this i am not able to access the required file and getting 403 error  but after this i am seen the

> error 403. Forbidden You don't have permission to access
>   XXX.com/application/views/XX/YY/ZZ.php on this server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: HI Thanks for reply, this is on an hosting server where i do not have the rights to edit httpd.conf and i believe there is nothing wrong with httpd.conf
can you please help me with an example .
Thanks in advance for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .htaccess in that folder with the following 2 lines

```
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
```

First one will allow you to access that folder and files contained in it.
And the second one will activate directory listing. Not sure if second line works on your server.