# Virtual host error

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, virtualhost, wamp-protocol

i'm trying to set up a virtual host on wamp to run some website tests. Although I have a virtual host error telling me to go into  **httpd.conf** file and then to un comment

> Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

I have done this multiple times I then get the same error and
 **Forbidden

> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.17
>   (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 Server at localhost Port 80.

but if I comment **Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** out, I can get onto my local host fine but not my webpage/project. Any ideas?

**Conf file**

```
 #
    # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
    # In particular, see
    # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
    # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
    #
    # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
    # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
    # consult the online docs. You have been warned.
    #
    # Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
    # of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
    # server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
    # with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/access_log"
    # with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the
    # server as "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log", whereas "/logs/access_log"
    # will be interpreted as '/logs/access_log'.
    #
    # NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
    # instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
    # If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
    # will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
    # an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.
    ServerSignature On
    ServerTokens Full

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
    # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
    # Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
    # same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
    # least PidFile.
    #
    ServerRoot "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.17"

    Define APACHE24 Apache2.4

    #
    # Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
    # for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
    #
    # Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
    # mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
    # other reason.
    #
    # Mutex default:logs

    #
    # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
    # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
    # directive.
    #
    # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
    #
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
    Listen 0.0.0.0:80
    Listen [::0]:80

    #
    # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
    #
    # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
    # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
    # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
    # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
    # to be loaded here.
    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #
    LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
    LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    #LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
    #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    #LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
    #LoadModule authnz_fcgi_module modules/mod_authnz_fcgi.so
    #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    #LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    #LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
    LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    #LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
    LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
    #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
    #LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
    #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    #LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
    #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
    #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
    #LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
    #LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    #LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
    #LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
    #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
    #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    #LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
    #LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
    #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    #LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
    #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
    #LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
    #LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    #LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    #LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
    #LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
    #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    #LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
    #LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
    #LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
    #LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
    #LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
    #LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
    #LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    #LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
    #LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
    #LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
    #LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
    #LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    #LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
    #LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
    #LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
    #LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
    #LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
    #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    #LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    #LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
    LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
    LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    #LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
    #LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so

    LoadModule php5_module "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/php5apache2_4.dll"

    <IfModule unixd_module>
    #
    # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
    # httpd as root initially and it will switch.
    #
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
    # running httpd, as with most system services.
    #
    User daemon
    Group daemon

    </IfModule>

    # 'Main' server configuration
    #
    # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
    # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
    # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
    # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
    #
    # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
    # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
    # virtual host being defined.
    #

    #
    # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
    # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
    # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
    #
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    #
    # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
    # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
    # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
    #
    # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
    #
    ServerName localhost:80

    HostnameLookups Off

    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/"

    #
    # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
    # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
    # directory (and its subdirectories).
    #
    # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
    # features.
    #
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    #
    # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
    # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
    # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
    # below.
    #

    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/">
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride all

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #

    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
        Require local
    </Directory>

    #
    # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
    # is requested.
    #
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    <Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
    </Files>

    #
    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    #ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    ErrorLog "C:/wamp64/logs/apache_error.log"

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>
        #
        # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
        # a CustomLog directive (see below).
        #
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

        <IfModule logio_module>
          # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
          LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
        # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
        # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
        # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
        # logged therein and *not* in this file.
        #
        CustomLog "C:/wamp64/logs/access.log" common

        #
        # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
        # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
        #
        #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule alias_module>
        #
        # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
        # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
        # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
        # Example:
        # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

        #
        # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
        # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
        # Example:
        # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
        #
        # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
        # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
        # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
        # the filesystem path.

        #
        # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
        # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
        # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
        # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
        # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
        # directives as to Alias.
        #
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/wamp64/cgi-bin/"

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule cgid_module>
        #
        # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
        # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
        #
        #Scriptsock cgisock
    </IfModule>

    #
    # "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
    # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
    #
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mime_module>
        #
        # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
        # filename extension to MIME-type.
        #
        TypesConfig conf/mime.types

        #
        # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
        # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
        #
        #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
        #
        # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
        # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
        #
        AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
        #
        # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
        # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
        #
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

        #
        # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
        # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
        # or added with the Action directive (see below)
        #
        # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
        # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

        # For type maps (negotiated resources):
        #AddHandler type-map var

        #
        # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
        #
        # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
        # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddType text/html .shtml
        #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    #MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

    #
    # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
    # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
    #
    # Some examples:
    #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
    #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
    #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
    #

    #
    # MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
    # returning the entire resource, or one of the special
    # values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
    # Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
    #MaxRanges unlimited

    #
    # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,
    # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
    # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
    # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted
    # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
    # broken on your system.
    # Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
    #
    EnableMMAP off
    EnableSendfile off

    # AcceptFilter: On Windows, none uses accept() rather than AcceptEx() and
    # will not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful for network
    # adapters with broken driver support, as well as some virtual network
    # providers such as vpn drivers, or spam, virus or spyware filters.
    AcceptFilter http none
    AcceptFilter https none

    # Supplemental configuration
    #
    # The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be
    # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of
    # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as
    # necessary.

    # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

    # Multi-language error messages
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

    # Fancy directory listings
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

    # Language settings
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

    # User home directories
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

    # Real-time info on requests and configuration
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

    # Virtual hosts
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

    # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

    # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

    # Various default settings
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

    # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
    <IfModule proxy_html_module>
    Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
    </IfModule>

    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
    #
    # Note: The following must must be present to support
    #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
    #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
    #
    <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>
    #
    # uncomment out the below to deal with user agents that deliberately
    # violate open standards by misusing DNT (DNT *must* be a specific
    # end-user choice)
    #
    #<IfModule setenvif_module>
    #BrowserMatch "MSIE 10.0;" bad_DNT
    #</IfModule>
    #<IfModule headers_module>
    #RequestHeader unset DNT env=bad_DNT
    #</IfModule>

    Include "C:/wamp64/alias/*"
```

Comment: Add the virtualhost code you used in `httpd-vhosts.conf`, this will help us understand where things go wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Answer (score 0):

Your `httpd-vhosts.conf` is most likely lacking a few edits and controls. Please check out this duplicate that should suit your situation. Please see both the accepted answer and the next highest voted for more information on `FollowSymLinks` and `Directory` permissions.

[Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

Comment: I tried to change <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory> 
but still no fix

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your Source folder, run these command(s):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Still, if you're facing problem, then check your .htaccess file, in the root folder. Change it to something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Plus, in your htdocs file:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

Change it to

```
User Administrators OR Your-User-Name
Group Administrators OR Your-User-Name
```

See, if that helps.