# Can't access to website after setting Apache using Virtualmin

Tags: apache, http, centos, vps

I set up Virtualmin on my VPS which comes with `Apache` server, but whenever I try to visit the hosted website there I get the below error. I am using `CentOS 7` on my VPS.

[image: forbidden error]

Apparently, many people have bumped into this problem and there are many ideas and probably solutions on StackOverflow but unfortunately, none of them worked for me.

Below are the things I tried.

- Making the `www` folder accesible by `apache` system user and not root. Did not work.
- Giving the proper permissions as the below image. 
  [image]
- Changing/adding lines of code for the `http.d` file as per this answer. [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)
- Disable SELinux

Any ideas what can be going wrong?

Comment: have you tried du command?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following:

- /var/log/apache2/access.log and error.log, to retrieve more info
- that there is an index.html in the folder that is being served by apache; check that permissions are properly set for that folder and its files. In a fresh Ubuntu server, after installing virtualmin and before creating a virtual server, if you visit the ip of the server you see /var/www/html/index.html (folder used by apache server that was pre-installed before installing virtualmin); in this case /var/www/html can have drwxr-xr-x, while index.html -rw-r--r--. If you are visiting one of the virtual servers, instead, the folders and files to check will be in /home//public_html

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be simple, I guess that you use default install config of you Virtualmin, that means that public_html will go to user home folder not to Apache www/html so, when you try to navigate where Apache say no (Forbidden 403)

To fix that first you should have index.html file in you public_html with such simple content:

```
<h1>Hello!</h1>
```