# I have a permission issue in wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

This is my htaccess ,it is simple wordpress htaccess but it is not working my server folder structure

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

[image]

And it is my server folder structure(site name /www/html/all wp file)

[image]

Comment: can you check if your root directory is set to AllowOverride All in apache2.conf file, you can also refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: when i up a simple HTML file it is ok but when i up wordpress file there is a permission problem