# You don't have permission to access / on this server! Error

Tags: debian, apache2

I have Debian 7.11 64-bit installed. I tried for a long time to get this server to work. I can access the web page perfectly fine on my server, but my friends and my phone can't access the web page on their devices. I have tried changing the "default" config file for apache2, but with no luck. Any suggestions?

```
**<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride none
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

**

If you need more information, I can provide.

EDIT:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory var/www/>
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Now i have change my code to this, still it does not work...

Comment: I am not an expert but doesn't <Directory /> refer to the root of your system? You really want to provide that access? About your problem you must be accessing using localhost, how are the rest trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue by setting the **options** directive either in the global directory setting in the **httpd.conf** or in the specific directory block in **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

By default, your global directory settings is `(httpd.conf line ~188)`:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

set the options to :
`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI`

Finally, it should look like:

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also try changing `Order deny,allow` and `Allow from all` lines  by `Require all granted`.

Comment: Also, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: First off, i dont have the httpd.conf file, been searching my directory and can't find it if i have it... I have also tried changing lines to require all granted, without any Lucky...