# .htaccess file blocking wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Getting the following error when trying to access my subdomain wordpress blog:

```
`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an 
ErrorDocument to handle the request.`
```

It's seems to be caused by a htaccess file that sits higher up in the public html folder. But i'm not sure what to change in this access file to fix the problem. The htaccess file contains:

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>`
```

Comment: can you post the directory structure and where the .htaccess is located?

Comment: The .htaccess file sits directly in the public html folder. And then the blog folder sits inside the Public Html folder. Does that make sense?

Comment: Here's a screen shot of the directory: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9PNXOOGdKsKTFhybUFvU0p5b0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i deleted my anwesr

Comment: @Catherine your htaccess looks fine. It looks like a permissions issue, see the permissions that your directory has. See if everyone has read access. Also look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10873295/4110233, you should find what you need there.