# Symfony3 assets status of 403 (Forbidden) on production server

Tags: symfony, configuration, assets, file-permissions

I just installed my SYmfony app on a server and the images are not displayed. I tried no modify the access rights on the web folder but it didnt work.

**What is the good way to configure access on a server with a symfony project ?**

I display my image like this :

```
<div class="user-info" style="background-image:url({{ asset('bundles/app/images/header/userbg.jpg') }});">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="{{ asset('uploads/')~user.image }}" width="48" height="48" alt="User" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The html code generated is like this :

```
<div class="user-info" style="background-image:url(/bundles/app/images/header/userbg.jpg);">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="/uploads/empty-profile.png" width="48" height="48" alt="User">
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand the good way to manage images on my app.
It is displayed well on my local server.

[image]

Comment: What are your permissions right now? And are you sure it's a permission problem, not your Symfony firewall?

Comment: @StephanVierkant It could be, I have no idea... I updated my post with the file permissions

Comment: What if you open userbg.jpg? Does it show a Symfony error or from your webserver?

Comment: I have the following message : Forbidden : You don't have permission to access /bundles/app/images/header/userbg.jpg on this server.

Comment: Using Apache? Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: I was just on it but I'm not sure about what tot do. Should I modify the .htaccess ? Because I'm currently using the default one provided by Symfony