# php-file responding correctly in local mode throws "fatal error" via http

Tags: php, apache, apache2, tcpdf

my tests with tcpfd run well as long as in terminal mode.
(see 1. and 2.). they don't when browser calls the same file via http (3.):
why?

1. local apache2 lists the file with appropriate rights:

tcPDFv6213 # ls -l include/tcpdf_font_data.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 313432 Dez  2  2016 include/tcpdf_font_data.php

2. starting rechnung.php via php provides the demanded rech.pdf correctly

tcPDFv6213 # php rechnung.php >rech.pdf (what is not under focus here)

3. unfortunately the same will not provided if invoked via http:

http://localhost/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/rechnung.php

the call provides me with "warning" and "fatal error".

Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/include/tcpdf_font_data.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/tcpdf.php on line 113

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/include/tcpdf_font_data.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/tcpdf.php on line 113

4. i tried to chmod root:root to www-data:www-data and v.v.
   then i tried to chmod rights for other to 6 and finally to 7.
   all that without any success - the error throwed remains the same ..

my system is linux (ubuntu) and mostly running well

---

edit: after chmod folder include to 755 (see comments, thans martin)
the response to http://localhost/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/rechnung.php changes from fatal error to warnings (concerning image related functions).

The issue reported here in my question has been solved. thank you, martin.

Comment: Since the error indicates a permission issue, it could be that only the root user has access. Try to check the apache process owner. To check this, try to use this `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` the owner should be `nobody`.

Comment: thank you, martin. i just added that who.php there with 
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>

include # ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 313432 Dez  2  2016 tcpdf_font_data.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     32 Jun  6 12:06 who.php

now:
http://localhost/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/include/who.php

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/include/who.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

(maybe too hot here today ..)

Comment: Try and refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: thank you, martin, i just transfered who.php into another folder where it ran without problems. so my interest was guided to the rights of the folder under inspection (include) which i had to chmod from 744 to 755. after that who.php runs fine with result "www-data" - as could be expected in local conditions. as reported in my question (4.) i just tried the script with root:root and www-data:www-data. do you have, please, an idea?

Comment: Hmm, what I provided was my initial ideas and input, if the problem still persists, I'd have to look into it more in depth, which I can't do as of right now I'm afraid.