# Laravel 5.6 DELETE and PUT 403 access forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, cors, laravel-5.6

Laravel version: 5.6

PHP version: 7.1

I finished my project and tested it locally. But when I uploaded it on a shared hosting site, I get two errors (I'm not sure if they're two separate errors):

> DELETE http://SomeAddress/patients/440627036 403 (Forbidden)
>
> Failed to load http://SomeAddress/patients/440627036: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://SomeAddress' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

It was CORS issue which I think I fixed. I was getting CORS error for only **PUT** and **DELETE** (I don't know why POST and GET were working!). I added the required headers and this error went away.These are the headers I added:

```
return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '10000');
```

But now I get another error (again only happens for **PUT** and **DELETE**) - (Is it related to Laravel or my shared hosting site or my backend code?):
[image: My new error]

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /patients/440627035 on this server.

Has my CORS issue been solved completely? How can I fix these errors?

Frontend (I use AngularJS $resource to send my HTTP requests):

```
this.patientRes = function () {
        return $resource(baseURL + 'patients/:id', {id: "@id"}, {
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            },
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }
        })
    };
```

Update:

My file structure was like this:

public_html/public/ and my files were here

I change it to:

public_html/ and my files are now here

Now I get this error:
[image]

Comment: What's the permissions setting on the /patients directory and/or document 1801207626762049?

Comment: No, they are not a directory. Actually, how can I say, they're just a URL address. There is no folder called patients. My data is in my database.

Comment: Maybe this answer for 'access forbidden' message from Apache will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11289275/3585500

Comment: But I can't change the Apache configuration on a shared hosting site.

Comment: Please show me your send request code

Comment: @TruongDang Dang I updated the question and added the one you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package:
[CORS Middleware for Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

In above Link given installation step also.