# Cannot Connect to Oracle Database 11g using PHP with XAMMP

Tags: php

Installed XAMMP and PHP 5.6.31 using Oracle instaclient_11_2 already in the C:\drive. Edited and enabled `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` in `php.ini`. Installed `php_oci8_11g.dll` in `C:\xampp\php\ext`.

What did i miss?

PHP returns:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OC\oci8.php on line 3

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr', 'localhost/orcl');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENTS_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}
else echo "connection successful";

?>
```

Comment: Need to enable comment php_oci8_12c.dll in php ini file and restart your appache. INI File PAHT: D:\xampp\php\php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have enable OCI but enabling OCI can be tricky.

1. Please closely follow this link:

   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html
2. Please see dll for OCI match php , that is 64bit php , 64bit OCI DLL, or 32bit php and 32bit OCI
3. Try copying php_oci8_xx.dll to system32. and restart pc. (not recommended but just to avoid the path issue, but first thing first make sure you follow above link carefully)

Thank you

Comment: Thanks Rob, much better now i got this error: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpinfo.php on this server. with a simple <?php
    phpinfo();
?>

Comment: i have granted all permissions in httpd.conf but the result is still the same..could anybody suggest what i have missed?

Comment: There can be several reasons for forbidden , i think go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server this might narrow your issue. more over try looking in to apache error logs, last thing try chmod 777  /phpinfo.php