# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.2.34 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on localhost xammp as I installed xamp and wordpress successfully. Now when I run the php code and provide the path in the Chrome browser, an error message appears that you do not have the permission to access...

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.2.34 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: did you allow read access to the website folder in your windows machine ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: @KenLee i have no idea about it how can  i check it ?

Comment: FYI: You can also get the same error message if (for some reason) the file you are trying to display is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and this is what worked for me

1. open your xammp file location
2. copy the .html  file to the htdocs folder
3. then type localhost/

Answer (score 0):

You may have to point to your project in the apache httpd folder. Here is an example where I created a project for a Udemy course:
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Complete HTML and CSS Learn Web Development with HTML and CSS/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Complete HTML and CSS Learn Web Development with HTML and CSS/public">

It was originally
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">

Restart your apache server and go to localhost and if you have an index file in the folder it will be rendered. Otherwise put the name of the file in the browser search box like this:
localhost/divspan.html as in my case.
Make sure you save a copy of the httpd file before modifying it so in case there is confusion you cab go back, a sort of version control mechanism for your httpd file.