# Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource - Laragon

Tags: wordpress, permissions, laragon

I had to install Windows again today. The Laragon folder stayed in the same place. I installed Laragon again too and it worked again but when I access the sites locally the images do not appear.

When I try to access the file via browser like this:

http://localhost:90/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/logo.png

The message appears:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

It seems to be a folder permission issue.

Does anybody know how to solve this? I use Windows 10.

I am using Laragon 4.0.16 with Apache httpd-2.4.47-win64.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can have several causes.

1. You may not have set the required permissions for the folder or file.
2. The .htaccess does not contain all the required information.
3. The VirtualHost has an invalid value.

Comment: We can eliminate .htaccess because all Laragon sites are having problems.

Comment: I tried the solutions from this link but none of them worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server